# Multiple Subtemplates in a Component

Tags: angular

I want to make a component in Angular2 that will render multiple sub-templates, e.g.

```
<div id="header">
  <!-- header template here -->
</div>
<div id="content">
  <!-- content template here -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <!-- footer template here -->
</div>
```

I can map a rendered html to any div, e.g. using mapping `[innerHtml]` of the header to a input property, like,

```
<my-container [headerText]="<b>HEADER</b>"></my-container>
```

but I want the component to be able to receive not only preprocessed html, but other angular2 templates as data, like:

```
<my-container 
    [headerText]="<other-component [input]>='value'</other-component>">
</my-container>
```

Is there a sane way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do this with `ng-content`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-container',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
```

and then use it in the markup.

```
<my-container>
  <div id="header">
    <!-- header template here -->
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- content template here -->
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <!-- footer template here -->
  </div>
</my-container>
```

If you want multiple placeholders then you can name them like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-container',
  template: `
    <ng-content select="my-header"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="my-content"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="my-footer"></ng-content>
  `
})
```

And use markup like

```
<my-container>
  <my-header>
    <!-- header template here -->
  </my-header>
  <my-content>
    <!-- content template here -->
  </my-content>
  <my-footer>
    <!-- footer template here -->
  </my-footer>
</my-container>
```

Comment: That's the issue, i'd need muti-part `ng-content` - one for the header, one for the content, one for the footer. I what the `<div id...>` code to be part of the component itself, and to inject the content.

Comment: Tnx, that hit the spot, checked it, works beautiful. Did not know about the select property.